# Image does not show up in php page when image link is passed from one page to the next using the web url in sessions

Tags: php, mysql, session

Here is the code :

```
if(isset($_SESSION['userName'])){

$src =$_GET['img'];
```

img is the image id through which the image http link in the server has been passed by appending it to the url from the previous php page

```
print "<img src=$src>";

}
```

The issue is that when I print or echo the link the image does not show up. However when I directly type the link it works ok. Any thoughts on resolving the issue can be helpful.

Comment: Can you please post all of your code

Comment: I am adding the print code like this print "<img src="$src">"; however it is not showing up above in the desc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

my thoughts are:

```
urlencode()
```

and

```
urldecode()
```

You need to mask your GET-data with urlencode() to send special characters. And you also need urldecode() to decode the encoded data.

Comment: something like this ? $url =urlencode($_GET['img']);

$url=urldecode($url);

Comment: After you mentioned I tried that; same issue remains.

Comment: In the first page i am encoding it as: (I am fetching the link from a mysql table)

$url = urlencode("<td>".$row['ImageDirectory']."<td>");

then I attach it to the url link using the img id.

In the second page i am decoding it as :

$url=(urldecode($_GET['img']));
print '<img src=$url>';

if i just print the $url it prints the link okay, with or without using encode/decode. However when I say print image the image would not come up as it was before.

Comment: why do you use td-tags in urlencode? in the first page use: $url = urlencode($row['imageDirectory']); then <a href="anylink?img=<?php echo $url ?>">anylink</a> and in the next page use <img src="<?php echo urldecode($_GET['img']) ?>">

Comment: Thank you it works! (With out encode/decode as well).l think the issue is that I was trying to print the image within the php body. Putting it as a img tag with the php code inside did the trick.As for the td tag ,that was unnecessary.

Comment: Is there a way we can print the image inside the php body? a print statement like :print '<img src=$url>'; does not work.

Comment: it is echo '<img src="'.$url.'">'; but this is really basic

Comment: its my 7th...may be 8th day into php.

Comment: then keep it going :)

Comment: :) do you know of a good book or link for php syntax? except w3s(many snippets are wrong here) and php.net.

Comment: I don't know any. But the Manual (php.net) and stackoverflow is basically what I use now. I also was active on php.de for a while. But it is in german. Regarding the Syntax you will find some Content here http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.php and regarding variables here http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php - happy learning :))

Comment: is it possible to carry over values in a similar manner to a 3rd  php page at the click of a button. I am using the following code echo '<FORM name="SUBMIT" action=9.php?itm=$itemname&uniq=$UniqueID method=POST>';
echo '<input type="submit" value="SUBMIT" >'; however the values are not getting passed instead all i get is the variable name.